# recyclerView inside scrollview resulting lagging and OutOfMemory

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Inside scrollView having two views,one containing viewPager and other containing recyclerView, also set 
`ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(mRvPosts,false);`

but still lagging and app crash.
Used pagination to load 10 images at a time on scrolling.
Used previous answer but nothing provide me the solution. I know recyclerView inside ScrollView/NestedScrollView is the problem as it not recycles recyclerViews items view. But do not know how to achieve it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/adsView">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="none">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <include layout="@layout/content_featured_posts" />


                    <include layout="@layout/content_recent_posts" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/adsView"
            layout="@layout/content_banner_ad" />

        <include layout="@layout/view_common_loader" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/lyt_recent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_20dp"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recent_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_15dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/view_all_recent"
            android:text="@string/recent_posts"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view_all_recent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_14dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="@string/view_all"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvRecent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/recent_title"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_10dp"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available
>       11-22 13:00:47.468 26842-27769/com.abc I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 2.117s for cause Alloc
>       11-22 13:00:47.468 26842-27769/com.abc I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
>       11-22 13:00:47.468 26842-27769/com.abc  I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
>       11-22 13:00:47.469 26842-28645/com.abc  I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
>       11-22 13:00:47.470 26842-28589/com.abc  I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
>       11-22 13:00:47.478 26842-28595/com.abc  I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
>       11-22 13:00:47.501 26842-27774/com.abc  I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc

Comment: Please post crash log also.

Comment: Post your error log. Use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`. Also set `recyclerview.setNestedScrolling(false)` .

Comment: @Piyush use it also but still app lags and crash..

Comment: Show error log.

Comment: @Piyush  added the Log report.. plz check it..

Comment: Are you loading images in adapter ?

Comment: @Jaymin added the log report..plz check it..

Comment: @Piyush yes brother

Comment: Load it with Glide

Comment: @Piyush used Glide to load images.. the problem is in the scrollView above recyclerView layout.. as it not allow the recyclerView to recycles items View, but needed scrollview as want to move above up on scroll

Answer (score 0):

try change **ScrollView** to **NestedScrollView**. then move **descendantFocusability** from **linearlayout** to **NestedScrollView**. it works in my case